# ipython emacs send code to interpreter

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

I am using ipython3 with emacs. 
It works but I would like to define a command that automatically send the highlighted code to the console. How can I do that?

This should be a short cut for the command :
M-w, C-x o , C-y, enter

That is:
copy, focus on the second buffer (that is the ipython3 terminal), copy and press enter. 
How can I do that?

This is my current .emacs file

```
(setq
 python-shell-interpreter "ipython3"
 python-shell-interpreter-args ""
 python-shell-prompt-regexp "In \\[[0-9]+\\]: "
 python-shell-prompt-output-regexp "Out\\[[0-9]+\\]: "
 python-shell-completion-setup-code
   "from IPython.core.completerlib import module_completion"
 python-shell-completion-module-string-code
   "';'.join(module_completion('''%s'''))\n"
 python-shell-completion-string-code
   "';'.join(get_ipython().Completer.all_completions('''%s'''))\n")
```

Comment: I have just found that it is actually all already setted. the command to pass code to the interpreter is already defined in the python emacs menu

Answer (score 1):

Checkout my Emacs extension emacs-ipython

https://github.com/burakbayramli/emacs-ipython

It shows the basic of running code through the ipython kernel. Getting error messages was not easy!